# Document type "book" and sections/chapters

Tags: header-footer, document-classes

I am using the class `"book"` for the first time. I am not sure if a code I copied is causing the following or this class type, but my problem is that there's a header on every other page saying `"CHAPTER #: CHAPTER HEADLINE"` on the top right, and a header on all pages in between saying `"PAGE #: SECTION HEADLINE"` on the top left.

Can I get rid of these, or at least modify them? I would like to get rid of the section headers, if possible.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but you should show us your code. Easiest way would be `\pagestyle{plain}`, most likely.

Comment: Those seem to be custom headers (due to the second one you mention). Are you using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) per chance? Is there a `\pagestyle{..}` command somewhere in your preamble?